# Threading prevents window from being created

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, windows-7

So I have a win32 program that creates a window with `HWND window=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"STATIC", L"Hi", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,0,0,120,20, hWnd, (HMENU)HI, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);`

And then after this I create a thread with `std::thread th=std::thread(print, hWnd);`
And launch it with `th.join();`
However, the window doesn't get created until the thread finishes executing, even though the thread is created after the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `th.join()` makes the parent thread wait for the child thread to finish executing before continuing on. You don't launch the thread with the join method, the thread launches when you create it. [Take a look](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) at the documentation for std::thread